# How to keep a total with an array?

Tags: java, arrays

Question: Write a program that creates two parallel arrays. The first is a string array that contains the names of items in a grocery list. The second is an array of prices for each item. Must satisfy the following conditions:

1. Print a numbered list of items in the first array with the prices.
2. Ask the user to select an item and specify a quantity.
3. Keep track of the running total for their shopping.
4. When they enter `0` to exit, print the total amount due.

I'm really confused with arrays, and am having trouble calculating the total. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's what I have so far...

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Items on the list");
    String[] list = {"eggs", "milk", "chicken", "cereal"};
    double[] prices = {2.00, 2.50, 4.50, 1.00};
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + list[i] + " " + prices[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("What item do you want");
    int item1 = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What quantity");
    int quantity1 = in.nextInt();
    double total1;
    double total2;
    double total = 0;
    while (item1 != 0) {
        System.out.println("Would you like another item");
        int item2 = in.nextInt();
        if (item2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(total);
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("What quantity?");
        int quantity2 = in.nextInt();
        total1 = (prices[item1 - 1] * quantity1);
        total2 = (prices[item2 - 1] * quantity2);
        total = total1 + total2;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is your concrete question?

Comment: To calculate a total, you add all the values together.  To keep a "running total" you simply have a value off to the side and add to that each value you insert into the array, as you insert the values.

Comment: In the above code you've messed up the loop a fair amount.  You need to figure out how to merge the "first item" and "next item" paths so you only do things once.  You don't want, eg, quantity1 and quantity2, just quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you are so close. You don't need to keep track of 2 items, just one. Also, you want to add to the total each iteration, not completely overwrite it. Currently, your total variable contains the price of the first item * quantity plus the *last* item entered.

```
System.out.println( "What do you want?" );
int item = in.nextInt();
double total = 0;

while( item != 0 )
{

    System.out.println( "How many?" );
    int quant = in.nextInt();

    // below is equiv to total += prices[item-1] * quant;
    total = total + (prices[item-1] * quant); // add to the total
                                              // initially it is 0, so after the first
                                              // iteration it is the cost of the first item*quantity.
                                              // and then keeps adding the new item*quantity to it.

    // notice this is done at the end of the loop so that the next statement that
    // gets executed is whether to continue or not.
    System.out.println( "Which item?" );
    item = in.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The beginning looks correct, but you messed the while loop a little bit up. I just made a scetch to show you how it should look (not tested):

```
double total = 0;
do {
  System.out.println("What item do you want?");
  int item = in.nextInt();
  if (item == 0)
    break;
  System.out.println("How many do you want?");
  int quantity = in.nextInt();
  total += quantity * prices[item - 1];
} while(true);
System.out.println("You have to pay " + total);
```